# Reference of an Array without Index in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Assume the following example:

```
uint8 myArr[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
uint8* ptr_a, ptr_b, ptr_c, ptr_test;
uint8** ptrptr_c;

void main(void)
{
    ptr_a = &myArr[4];  // Address of myArr
    ptr_b = myArr;      // Address of myArr  
    ptr_c = &myArr;     // --> Address of myArr again?! <---
    ptrptr_c = &myArr;  // --> Address of myArr again?! <--

    ptr_test = &ptr_a   // Address of ptr_a (whose content points to myArr)
}
```

That `ptr_a` and `ptr_b` contain the address of `myArr` is perfectly clear to me. 
But I would've actually assumed, that `ptr_c` would contain some kind of address where the address of `myArr` is stored (analogue to `ptr_test`).

So, why does `ptr_c` (or `ptrptr_c`) contain the address of `myArr` ?

Comment: `uint8* ptr_a, ptr_b, ptr_c, ptr_test;` is wrong. `uint8 *ptr_a, *ptr_b, *ptr_c, *ptr_test;` is correct. or: `typedef uint8_t* uint8_p; uint8_p ptr_a, ptr_b, ptr_c, ptr_test;`. Your choice.

Comment: `ptr_a = &myArr[4];  // Address of myArr`......absolutely not.... Most probably the address of `ptr_a` pointer...

Comment: Take the compiler's warnings serious. Fix the code until none are issues anymore. When fixing, do not (blindly) cast away any warnings.

Comment: There is no distinct variable that holds the address of `myArr`, except `myArr` itself. The array name can be seen as evaluating to the address of the first element, in most contexts (`sizeof` is a shining exception).

Comment: `ptr_a = &myArr[4];  // Address of myArr`, no it is the address of `&myArr[4]`, element which is actually out of bounds, the last element of the `myArr` array being `myArr[3]`.

Comment: `ptr_test = &ptr_a` is this even valid?

Comment: @MichaelWalz you are allowed to take the address of the 1 behind the last element, but you are not allowed to dereference it. `ptr_a = &myArr[4];` is a correct line, the comment is wrong.

Comment: @mch I wrote "the _element_ is out of bounds". I didn't write that taking it's address is wrong.

Comment: For any `T a[N];` the following is true: `(uintptr_t) &a[0] == (uintptr_t) &a` which is the same as `(uintptr_t) a == (uintptr_t) &a`

Answer (score 4):

- Never declare several variables on the same line. Or you will write  bugs like `uint8* ptr_a, ptr_b, ptr_c, ptr_test;` Only the first variable is declared as a pointer.
- ptr_c = &myArr is not a valid pointer conversion, since the type of `&myArr` is `uint8 (*)[4]`, an *array pointer*. An array pointer works just as any other pointer type, though it points at whole arrays. So `my_array_pointer+1` gives you the *next array*, just like `my_int_pointer+1` gives you the next int (the next pointed-at item).

  An array pointer points to the whole array, so it will contain the address of the first item. Which is why `myArr` and `&myArr` gives the same address (but different types).

  You cannot assign an array pointer to an ordinary pointer. This line should not compile without warnings/errors.
- `ptrptr_c = &myArr;` is the same invalid pointer conversion, except `ptrptr_c` is a `uint8**`.

There is a common misunderstanding that pointer-to-pointers are somehow related to arrays. This is simply wrong, they are not related to arrays whatsoever. The origin of this misunderstanding is look-up tables like this:

```
int** pptr = malloc(n*sizeof(*pptr)); 
...
pptr[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(*pptr[i]));
```

Bad books/tutorials/teachers tend to say that the above is a 2D array, which it is not.

See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) to unlearn this incorrect belief. It also explains array pointers a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Why `again`? You apply 2 times the same code.

It does not care what type is variable and what you assign to it. You assign to `ptr_c`and `ptrptr_c` the same value. So they both contain the same value. This is in general veery wrong concept and compiler should warn you or give you error.

Correct value would be:

```
uint8 myArr[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
uint8 *ptr_a, *ptr_b, *ptr_c, *ptr_test;
uint8** ptrptr_c;

void main(void) {
    //ptr_a = &myArr[4];  // Address of myArr //WRONG!!!!
    ptr_a = &myArr[3]; //If you want last address, use 3, because 3 is last index.

    ptr_b = myArr;      // Address of myArr, OK!!  

    //ptr_c = &myArr;     // WRONG: if ptr_c is pointer to uint8_t then assing uint8_t pointer to it.
    ptr_c = myArr;      //Correct!

    //This should be compiler error something like:
    //a value of type "uint8_t (*)[]" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "uint8_t **
    ptrptr_c = &myArr;  // Address of myArr again? No, error.

    //This is WRONG
    ptr_test = &ptr_a;   // WRONG:
    ptr_test = ptr_a;    //THIS IS OK

}
```

Comment: `ptr_a = &myArr[4];` is not wrong, the comment is wrong. `for (; ptr_b < ptr_a; ptr_b++) printf("%d ", (int) *ptr_b);` is a valid usage of it.

Comment: Look `myArr`size. You are outside array bounds.

Comment: You are not allowed to dereference `&myArr[4]`, but you can take the address. Read the C99 standard $6.5.6.8: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.6

Comment: Ok. I do understand your point. But bad idea! as it will fail somewhere 4sure.

Comment: "It does not care what type is variable and what you assign to it." Umm... the compiler does. Which is why those two lines don't compile - the types are not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

```
uint8* ptr_a, ptr_b, ptr_c, ptr_test;
```

Only `ptr_a` has been declared as a pointer to `uint8`; everything else has been declared as `uint8t`.

Based on your assignments, the right types for each variable are

```
uint8 *ptr_a, *ptr_b, (*ptr_c)[4], (*ptrptr_c)[4], **ptr_test;
```

The expression `&myArr[4]` has type `uint8 *`, and evaluates to the address of the object one past the last element of the array (remember that arrays in C are indexed starting at 0).

The expression `myArr` is implicitly converted ("decays") from type "4-element array of `uint8`" to "pointer to `uint8`" and the value of the expression is the address of the first element in the array - it's equivalent to writing `&myArr[0]`.

Because of the presence of the `&` operator, `myArr` isn't implicitly converted to a pointer, so the type of `&myArr` is "pointer to 4-element array of `uint8`".  The address of an array is the same as the address of the first element of the array, so `&myArr[0]`, `myArr`, and `&myArr` will all yield the same value, but the won't all have the same type.

And finally, the type of `&ptr_a` is "pointer to pointer to `uint8`".

And, `main` returns `int`, not `void` - use `int main( void )` instead of `void main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C, can decay - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461449/1347519).

This means that in the following, `ptr_a` and `ptr_b` are equivalent (the same).

Also, be aware that in the following, the assignment of `ptr_d` is not valid (see the warning below).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint8_t myArr[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

    uint8_t *ptr_a = myArr;
    uint8_t *ptr_b = &(myArr[0]);
    uint8_t *ptr_c = &(myArr[4]);
    uint8_t *ptr_d = &myArr;  /* <-- invalid (warning raised) */

    printf("ptr_a: %p\n", ptr_a);
    printf("ptr_b: %p\n", ptr_b);
    printf("ptr_c: %p\n", ptr_c);
    printf("ptr_d: %p\n", ptr_d);

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc aa.c -o aa && ./aa
aa.c: In function ‘main’:
aa.c:9:19: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  uint8_t *ptr_c = &myArr;
     ^
```

```
$ ./aa
ptr_a: 0x7fffdda58cf0
ptr_b: 0x7fffdda58cf0
ptr_c: 0x7fffdda58cf4
ptr_d: 0x7fffdda58cf0
ptr_e: 0x7fffdda58cf0
```

Comment: @tilz0R Configure GCC as a standard conforming compiler: `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. That being said, the C standard has nothing called errors or warnings. It only requires that the compiler gives a "diagnostic", which is any form of message to the programmer. So a compiler that just gives a warning is still conforming.